# Installing CKAN on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ckan

I have tried to install CKAN on Ubuntu 12.04 server using instructions at http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/index.html unsuccessfully. I have tried from package or from source, and have tried different versions of ubuntu etc. No luck. Something is always missing or failing (I assume various packages/web links no longer available). I am using a Dell Latitude E5430. 
Does anyone have updated instructions using the latest stable Ubuntu release please? thanks

Comment: The documented installation instructions do work for Ubuntu 12.04. I think you need to edit your question to ask about a specific problem you're having with the install.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I was trying to install on Ubuntu server, tried on the desktop and succeeded! Had to apply fixes early on - for example on running update> got:

W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 ... etc

used a bug fix at:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error